# El Capitan's Disk Utility won't format new 3 TB drives higher than 800 GB

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

My iMac Mid.2010 running OS X EL Capitan v10.11.6 will not format any of my brand new 2 x 3 TB SATA drives and although I tried any other format like exFat, etc, it keeps making them no higher than 800 gigs.  I do connect each drive to the iMac with a "kdLinks HDD docking station" and a SATA-to-USB2 interface cable. The purpose is to use these 2 drives for Time Machine backups. What am I doing wrong?

Update:

[image]

Also:

```
2017-01-14 12:59:38.663 defaults[9465:6786462] 
The domain/default pair of (/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist, MaxSize) does not exist
```

Also from `mount`:

```
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /Volumes/OLDisk (hfs, local, journaled)
/dev/disk2s2 on /Volumes/SATADisk2 (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled)
```

Comment: What have you been doing thus far? Also can you post the output of `diskutil list`

Comment: What drive manufacturer?

Comment: Forgive me. It is a Seagate, sold by Dell as Constellation ES.2

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably related to the [2.2 TB (or 2 TiB) limit](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2028834&seqNum=7). Your disks either have an MBR (instead of a PMBR) or it's a limitation of the firmware of the kdLinks HDD disk station.

Check the disks after getting their disk identifiers with `disktuil list` with `sudo gpt -r show diskX` with diskX the disk identifiers of the external disks (e.g. disk1 and disk2).

If you get an output like this:

```
gpt show: /dev/disk1: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     .....
```

destroy the MBRs and add a proper GUID partition table.

To destroy the MBR and restore a proper GUID pt use:

```
diskutil umountDisk diskX
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/diskX bs=512 count=1
```

Destroy the GUID partition table and create a new one:

```
diskutil umountDisk diskX
sudo gpt destroy diskX
sudo gpt create -f diskX
```

with diskX: once more the disk identifiers of your external disks.

Be sure to use the proper diskX or you may accidentally delete valid disks!

---

After removing the MBR you often/sometimes have to completely eject the drive (or reboot your Mac) for the changes to take effect.

---

Update:

With your partition data posted one can definitely say it's a 2 TiB problem:

The default size of the disk is [5,860,533,168 blocks](http://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/constellation-fam/constellation-es/constellation-es-2/es-es/docs/100633157h.pdf). Your gpt output shows a size of 1,565,565,872 blocks. The difference is exactly 4,294,967,296 blocks which are 2<sup>32</sup> blocks or 2 TiB.

Comment: So you said I need a newer machine instead of this old iMac?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @opgalloso No, the iMac 2010 and the OS installed shouldn't be affected by the 2TiB limit. It's either a problem of the disk station's firmware or maybe the USB2SATA controller. It may be salvaged by attaching it to a Windows PC and completely repartitioning it.

Answer (score -1):

Fire up terminal and do:

`sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist MaxSize`

if it outputs a `integer`, like `1024000`

`sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist MaxSize`

`diskutil list` to see that this drive is visible, then create a 
new hfs partition (put proper device where `/dev/diskNumber` is):
`diskutil partitionDisk /dev/diskNumber 1 GPT HFS+ volumeName 100%`

Parameters explained: `1` is the number of partitions, `GPT` is the table scheme, `HFS+` is the filesystem and `100%` is the Volume size. To format 1 HFS+ Volume on the entire drive you do:

`diskutil partitionDisk /dev/diskX 1 GPT HFS+ volumeName 100%`

To get 2 partitions, each having 50% of your drive:

`diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk5 2 GPT HFS+ firstVolume 50% secondVolume HFS+ 50%`

If you want just the GPT table without HFS formatting:
change `HFS+` to `%noformat%` 
You can try **APFS**, Apple's new HFS replacement, its still in-dev though and I don't know if ElCaptain supports it, and I definitely **don't recommend it** for a TM backup, still you can try if it creates the volume

`diskutil apfs create /dev/diskNumber`

and you will get a warning message that's not very encouraging for backup but see if it creates the partition if HFS+ fails- you can reformat them.

Let me know what kind of errors you get, and what `defaults read` tells about MaxSize (if any). Please paste any `diskutil` output somewhere if you have issues with partitioning.

Update: Why the down votes people :(

Comment: Possibly because someone asked for a match & you gave them the formula for rocket propellant ;) Also, APFS is very much beta only right now. It's not even cross-compatible between 10.12.1 & 10.12.2 - see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67007

Comment: Well, you got a point although I don't see any harm in that answer and I edited the `less humorous` comments. Down-vote without any comment isn't very helpful either, I need to keep my (~lack of) humour out.

Comment: See http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2921/why-was-my-answer-down-voted-and-most-importantly-why-did-it-not-require-the-us?cb=1

Comment: I knew it! Damn you Cat!

Comment: Sorry guys, big newB to these forums. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the output of `sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist MaxSize`, its probably because that a system-wide `MaxSize` is set.

This command **can't harm your system in any way**- it will simply read 
the value of `MaxSize` within your `TimeMachine` config .plist file.

`diskutil` command will also not harm your system- it is meant for partitioning (DiskUtility.app is a UI for it) and it is more verbose then DiskUtil. Let me know what those commands says.

If I remember right, there was some TM limit and 800gb sounds just right.
You can also post the whole TimeMachine configuration output, will be easier to check it for some clues:

`sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist`

**update** please, post the output from `diskutil list` and `mount` as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51639/discussion-on-answer-by-pjj-el-capitans-disk-utility-wont-format-new-3-tb-driv).